# Can't display my google map with canvas

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty finding a solution to the following:

I'm writing a JavaScript web page and attempting to display a Google map (Google API) with a canvas tag in the html body.

So far it only displays the map and the canvas separate.

[image]

Comment: Can we get the code, and not an image?

Comment: You're setting the map to the `div` with the id "map". I think you want to set it to the `canvas` with the id "mycanvas"

Comment: <body>
        <div id="map"> </div>
        <canvas  id="mycanvas" width="1875" height="800" style="border: 12px solid">
          
        </canvas>
      
        <script>

            function initMap() {
         
                var map = new
                        google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            zoom: 4,
                            center: {lat: 42.9849, lng: -81.2453}
                        });
            }
        </script>
    </body>

Comment: thanks QuietOran i will try this again it was not working earlier

Answer (score 0):

You have it set up so that the elements naturally flow. That means the canvas falls below the map naturally. If you want the `<canvas>` element to be placed *on top of* the `<div>` containing the map, you'll need to use CSS to do that. There are various ways, but given the dimensions you've used, it would look something like this in your CSS:

```
canvas {
  position: absolute:
  width: 100vw;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

You could go a step further and set the width and height attributes on the canvas element in code if you wanted to be precise:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.height = '400';
canvas.width = innerWidth();
```